# Change static network address on a non-running windows image

Tags: windows, networking, installation

on Linux it is quite easy to do the following steps, I am wondering if this is feasible with windows 10.

1. Mount a non-running linux disk image
2. Edit the IP address and netmask
3. Boot the linux os --> and it comes up with the new settings

Is something similar possible in windows?
Is there any proper way to do this, or does it end up with hacking the registry binary files?

Comment: Windows keeps most of its configuration in registry files. You can find a [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1125302/windows-10-registry-settings-for-ip-address) on superuser. _Samba_ has a **regedit** utility, but there is a catch: when you tell Windows 10 to poweroff it hibernates instead, so the filesystem is unmountable.

Comment: Maybe this would be easier to answer with more context. If you are using this image as a template for new Windows servers and that is why you are assigning a new IP to this powered off image, then you might want to look at [sysprep](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--generalize--a-windows-installation). Sysprep will allow you to set the IP address for a new deployment, but read the docs completely, "generalize the Windows installation to remove unique PC-specific information from a Windows installation, which allows you to safely reuse your image." I

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the Windows 10 registry with the Windows Recovery Environment; details are here: https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/edit-registry-offline-windows-re/

The specific IP address in the registry will be located somewhere here, depending upon the network interface you're trying to change: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Services/Tcpip/Parameters/Interfaces`